# svm file format in weka

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka

I want to classify texts using svm (smo) in weka. The file I have, contains some sentences (Persian) and a word in front of each sentence which shows its class. The question is: should I change these sentences to a binary vector and give these vectors to weka as input or is it enough if I just turn the sentences to vector by choosing "string to word vector" in weka itself?

sample file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohpyortve8jbwhe/shoor.arff?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried these two options? Does any of them appear to work better than the other (or not work at all)?

Comment: @ etov, I tried the second one. (the sentences as input). and it returns the answer but I don't know if it is right or no. for the first one I don't have any idea, according to what factor I should change the words to vector. In fact, I don't know which one is scientific.

Comment: There is the StringToWordVector converter in Weka which can do what you want. As for whether this is scientific, rather ask that at http://stats.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, it works with choosing "string to word vector" in weka, it's better to change the sentences to vectors according to 1000 most frequent words or any other features. It works faster.